# "He added" vs. "Did he add" (inversion after negative adverb)

Tags: past-tense, question-mark

I'm reading a book, and I found a sentence where I don't understand the grammar. It seems as the writer wants to write a statement, but uses the structure of a question. The sentence is highlighted in the following paragraph:

> In the first ten paragraphs, he touted his engineering skills, including his ability to design bridges, waterways, cannons, armored vehicles, and public buildings. Only in the eleventh paragraph, at the end, ***did he add* that he was also an artist**. "Likewise in painting, I can do everything possible," he wrote.
>
> Isaacson, Walter. (2017) Leonardo da Vinci.

Shouldn't that sentence start with "*he added*" instead of "*did he add*" since it's not a question? If it's correct, is it something people usually use when they speak, or is it more like something you would find in books?

Comment: It's because of the **only** at the beginning of the sentence, which starts a clause which is to be completed with ...did he... Similarly, "only then did he make a decision."

Comment: It's simply a reordering of "he did".

Answer (score 1):

In older Modern English, it was not uncommon for a sentence that was fronted by an adverb to have the subject and verb inverted:

I love her dearly." - "Dearly do I love her.

"They fought long." - "Long did they fight."

This is now retained chiefly in literary use and in certain contexts:

> Random Idea English at http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/09/exploring-inversion-and-fronting.html has a good explanation
>
> **Inversion and fronting**
>   Inversion is often used in connection with fronting. Sometimes fronting involves inversion, often it doesn't. Sometimes that inversion is obligatory, sometimes it isn't.
>
> •  Fronting of a negative adverb, with obligatory inversion.
>
> He had never seen such a wonderful sunset. (standard word order)
>
> Never had he seen such a wonderful sunset. (fronted with inversion)
>
> •  **Fronting of a prepositional phrase, with optional inversion**
>
> A large dog lay in front of the fireplace. (standard word order)
>
> In front of the fireplace, lay a large dog. (fronted with inversion)
>
> In front of the fireplace, a large dog was chewing a bone. (fronted, no inversion)
>
> •  **Fronting of wh-clause - here inversion is not possible**
>
> I've no idea why she's late. (standard word order)
>
> Why she's late, I've no idea. (fronted, no inversion)

The commonest uses are “so do I” and “neither do I”